# What do you call males in their late teens/early twenties?

Tags: word-choice

For example, what word would I use to say like “Boys are cute” or “Guys are cute”? I’m 19, so what word would fit me? 男？

Comment: Its not uncommon to use 子（こ）if you perceive their age or social/workplace status to be similar or below yours. A common phrase is あの子 or あの子たち meaning that (guy/girl) in both singular and plural.

Answer (score 1):

I think [男子]{だんし} is the appropriate word here.
Take for example [this article](https://cancam.jp/archives/558971). 
Note that [男子]{だんし} and [女子]{じょし} are used when referring to a group of boys or girls respectively, never when referring to an individual.

Comment: thank you! so then, how would i say “that boy/guy is really cute?” for an individual?